# Почему не могу молучить значение свойств?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

С наступающим всех.

Прописал JS код

```js
$(
 function(){
     alert('111')
    var elem1 = document.getElementsByClassName("li.technical > div > div svg.clip-svg-1")[0];
    alert('222')
    var style = window.getComputedStyle(elem1, null).getPropertyValue('width');
    alert('333')
    alert(style);
 });
```

```css
li.technical > div > div svg.clip-svg-1 {
    width: 15px;
    height: 8px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 35px;
    top: 7px;
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<li class="technical" onclick="asideFiltrs()"> <!-- одна строка из целого списка с N строками -->
    <div>
        <div>
            <svg class="clip-svg-1">
                <rect class="svg-background" width="15px" height="8px"></rect>
                <image class="clip-svg" width="15px" height="8px" xlink:href="/male-cosmetics/img/st_.png"></image>
            </svg>
            <h3>Бренд</h3>
            <svg class="clip-svg-2">
            <rect class="svg-background" width="15px" height="8px"></rect>
            <image class="clip-svg" width="15px" height="8px" xlink:href="/male-cosmetics/img/st_active.png"></image>
                                        
            </svg>
        
     </div> 
</div>
</li>
```

`alert('222')` всплывает. На получении Style и Value функция останавливается. `alert('333')` не всплывает.

Что делаю не так, почему не получаю Value [0] елемента из всего списка? Подскажите.

Что интересно, указывая Class который в DOM применяется только один раз, Value всплывает.

Comment: Там же пишут в чём дело... " Failed to execute 'getComputedStyle' on 'Window': parameter 1 is not of type **'Element'.**"

Comment: Ну и метод getElements**ByClassName**  очевидно даёт в себе подсказку, какой именно селектор надо вписывать в него......явно не всю цепочку дерева...... может быть надо querySelector (querySelectorAll)  использовать?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский где пишут, где смотрите?  В F12 не вижу, ошибки не светятся, ну или их не вижу.

Comment: да. в консоли пишут......функция не останавливается...она просто доооооолго выполняется...потому что это делается на window ....вместо alert сделай хотя бы console.log.... и жди....а лучше пока убери... и увидишь

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, спасибо.

Comment: `document.querySelector('.selector')`

Answer (score 0):

Получил конечный, желаемый результат.

```
var elem1 = window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementsByClassName("clip-svg-1")[0]).getPropertyValue('display');
```